# Google Analytics: Landing Page Entrance Paths

Tags: google-analytics

In GA, when you go to Behavior > Site Content > Landing Pages > select "/" (homepage) and then choose "Entrance Paths" from the top nav tab, you receive information about:

**"User started at this landing page: / 
then viewed these pages"**

And GA loads the top 10 second pages the user clicked to.

In my results, / appears in the number 5 slot.

How can a user land on the / (homepage) and then view the / (homepage)? Is the information incorrect? Or does it mean the user clicked the homepage again?

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Best,
Catherine

Answer (score 0):

it means that they have refreshed mainpage or they have entered its URL address that its not counted as another subpage, like for example example.com/#partofpage , perhaps you are also executing google analytics with ajax.

It would be easier to find solution when you will give url of this website.

Regards, Grzegorz